# How to prevent pip install from github from adding a spurious slash and failing?

Tags: git, pip

I'm trying to pip-install (in editable mode, but the problem is identical for non-editable mode too) from a github repo, but it is failing as follows:

```
$ pip install git+ssh:git@github.com/jupyterhub/nativeauthenticator.git#egg=nativeauthenticator
Collecting nativeauthenticator
  Cloning ssh:///git@github.com/jupyterhub/nativeauthenticator.git to /tmp/pip-install-dqnyu101/nativeauthenticator_824b55eecd3440c08150d3a91a521c08
  Running command git clone -q ssh:///git@github.com/jupyterhub/nativeauthenticator.git /tmp/pip-install-dqnyu101/nativeauthenticator_824b55eecd3440c08150d3a91a521c08
  ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: Temporary failure in name resolution
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
WARNING: Discarding git+ssh:///git@github.com/jupyterhub/nativeauthenticator.git#egg=nativeauthenticator. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q ssh:///git@github.com/jupyterhub/nativeauthenticator.git /tmp/pip-install-dqnyu101/nativeauthenticator_824b55eecd3440c08150d3a91a521c08 Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nativeauthenticator (unavailable)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for nativeauthenticator (unavailable)
```

The problem appears to be a spurious slash (see the "Running command" line). In fact, manually running `git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/jupyterhub/nativeauthenticator.git /tmp/pip-install-dqnyu101/nativeauthenticator_824b55eecd3440c08150d3a91a521c08` works just fine. Using `git+https` or `git+git` produce very similar errors with a spurious slash (but I really want to use `git+ssh`). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
$ pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from ~/repo/github/nativeauthenticator_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: Doesn't `git+ssh` expect URL syntax? E.g. `git+ssh://git@github.com/jupyterhub/nativeauthenticator.git#egg=nativeauthenticator` instead of what you're currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/jupyterhub/nativeauthenticator.git#egg=jupyterhub-nativeauthenticator
```